# Unable to run Laravel Dusk out of the box

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I followed the instructions from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk).  But I am having this error and can't figure out why.

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\Auth\LoginTest::testLogin
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php on line 127

/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.php:33
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:127
/var/www/xxxxxx/tests/DuskTestCase.php:40
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:192
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:816
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:193
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:93
/var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:64
/var/www/xxxxxx/tests/Browser/Auth/LoginTest.php:27
```

Here is my DuskTestCase

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox', // as suggested in one of the forums but didn't work
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:3402', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I have installed facebook/webdriver but same error.  I am using Ubuntu and Docker.  Chrome also isn't my default browser, changing that didn't help.  What am I msising here?

Comment: What version of Dusk are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Browser drivers are downloaded to **\vendor\laravel\dusk\bin** within your laravel app.

[image: chromedrive location]

Navigate to the location from your file explorer and run the executable file (depending on your Operating system, mine is **Windows** and I'm running **chromedriver-win.exe**). You should see this

[image: terminal showing port being used]

This is the port number to use in your **DuskTestCase.php** file

[image]

Also, you need to ensure you set your **APP_URL** variable in the **.env** file to the URL accessible from your browser (mine is APP_URL=http://localhost:8888).

Note: I'm not using port **9515** in my **.env** file.

I hope that helps.